# Problem fitting GAMM4 with interaction term: "fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 1 column / coefficient"

Tags: lme4-nlme, panel-data, generalized-additive-model, mgcv, gamm4

I am trying to use a gamm4() (mgcv package) equation to model 1) how brain regional volumes change over time and 2) how brain regional volume development differs between males and females. My data is longitudinal with 435 brain scans collected from ~85 participants (2-20 scans per participant). Here is snippet of my data in readable text format. The problem occurs regardless of how many data points are included.

```
     sub     scan ses  age male Lamyvol Ramyvol     ICV
1  10001 PS13_001   1 3.07    1     836     745 1460830
2  10001 PS14_006   2 3.74    1     923     833 1524028
3  10002 PS13_002   1 3.16    0     685     507 1506471
4  10002 PS14_007   2 3.74    0     687     577 1446722
5  10006 PS14_001   1 4.13    1     751     952 1626957
6  10006 PS14_053   2 3.65    1     959    1063 1782564
7  10006 PS14_120   3 5.13    1     865    1050 1697070
8  10006 PS15_061   4 5.55    1     884    1079 1754870
9  10006 PS15_138   5 6.01    1     988    1039 1792199
10 10006 PS19_010   6 9.27    1     910    1261 1772289
11 10007 PS14_054   2 2.99    0     659     704 1320229
12 10007 PS14_121   3 3.47    0     706     747 1316031
13 10007 PS15_062   4 3.89    0     712     837 1390056
14 10007 PS15_139   5 4.35    0     737     753 1419400
15 10007 PS19_009   6 7.60    0     746     846 1473368
16 10008 PS14_003   1 3.32    1     648     579 1379766
17 10008 PS14_046   2 3.72    1     717     592 1371638
18 10008 PS14_079   3 4.20    1     760     655 1402349
19 10008 PS15_040   4 4.77    1     761     777 1558745
20 10008 PS16_001   5 5.29    1     740     719 1652214
21 10008 PS16_045   6 5.81    1     715     804 1648004
22 10008 Ps17_018   7 6.80    1     755     768 1585690
23 10009 PS14_004   1 2.89    1     835     793 1509158
24 10009 PS14_070   2 3.43    1     894     877 1536631
```

sub = participant ID,
scan = unique scan ID,
ses = scan number,
age = age at time of scan,
male = sex (male = 1, female = 0),
Lamyvol = left amygdala volume,
Ramyvol = right amygdala volume,
ICV = intracranial volume

I tried fitting the following model with gamm4():

```r
Lamygamm4 <- gamm4(Lamyvol ~ s(age) + s(age, by = male) + male + 
    ICV_rescale1000, data = amyvols, random = ~(1|sub))
```

I get the following warning:

```r
fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 1 column / coefficient
```

When I remove either the interaction term or the main effect of "male", the warning disappears. However, I need both in the equation to fully answer my research question. I have also found that the warning disappears when I turn "male" in the interaction into an ordered.factor:

```r
Lamygamm4 <- gamm4(Lamyvol ~ s(age) + s(age, by = ordered_male) + 
    male + ICV_rescale1000, data = amyvols, random = ~(1|sub))
```

However, I have read online that adding the ordered factor results in the gamm making one of my sexes a "reference" to which the other is compared. While this works for my investigation into sex effects, I read that the "s(age)" term will then only model the "reference" sex which is not what I want.

Based on my reading, I suspect that my data has some type of collinearity resulting in the matrix deficiency warning. However, I do not know if/how it can be resolved. I have also tried coding my "male" variable as 1s/2s and -1s/+1s and turning variables into unordered factors (none of which work).

Anybody know what is going on and how I can resolve it?

Comment: Please edit to add the data in a readable text format, and not only as an image.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Sorry about that, thanks for the edits. I have added the data in readable text format.

Comment: Is `male` coded as a factor in the first model? If not you'll get a varying coefficient model as it things `male` is a continuous variable. That the issue goes away when you make `age` and ordered factor suggest this is the problem

Comment: @GavinSimpson Thank you for your comment! No, it is not coded as a factor in the first model. I had the same thought as you though so have already tried: `Lamygamm4 <- gamm4(Lamyvol ~ s(age) + s(age, by = factor(male)) + factor(male) + ICV_rescale1000, data = amyvols, random = ~(1|sub))`. Unfortunately, the problem persists.

Comment: @GavinSimpson The problem also persists if I code sex as "female"/"male" instead of using 0s/1s. I can't figure out why it only works with the ordered factor.